# React button onClick property:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

What is the difference between (1) and (2) in **React**?

```
onClick={()=>handleDelete(id)} -------(1)

onClick={handleDelete(id)} ----------(2)
```

why does (2) cause infinite loops whereas (1) works just fine?

I couldn't find any documentation on onClick in react being only able to take in functions. I'm also a bit confused as to how the Html and JS onClick property is different from react  So any documentation links will also be highly appreciated.

The code snippet in question:

```
<button
    className="btn btn--danger"
    onClick={()=>handleDelete(id)}
>
    Delete
</button>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The second one runs instantly and the first one runs when the button is clicked

Comment: but isn't onClick supposed to mean that react will only render the changes when the button is clicked? Why does this function get called infinite times automatically without the button getting clicked?

Comment: But you are running the function instead of passing it as a prop. It's like instead of giving someone a number, you would just call yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever is in the curly braces is what is returned to the listener. The listener is expecting a *function* that will be called when the event is fired.

1. `onClick={handleDelete(id)}`

This won't work because you're calling `handleDelete` *immediately* and assigning the result of calling that function to the listener. That function may return an explicit value or `undefined` (note: that explicit value may be a a *new* function (closure) which can be assigned to the listener - but in this case I doubt this is happening).

2. `onClick={() => handleDelete(id)}`

This will work because you're assigning a function to the listener, and when the event is fired it will call that function which, in turn, will call `handleDelete(id)`.

3. `onClick={handleDelete}`

This will also work because you're passing a *reference* to the `handleDelete` function to the listener, and that function will get called when the event is fired.

(Note: doing it this way would mean that the component would need to be rewritten to have a `data-id` attribute that the function can pick up because you're no longer sending an explicit `id` argument to `handleDelete` when you call it.)

Answer (score 0):

Before explaining the differences, you have mismatching braces in the second one.

The second one is called an invoked function. That means when the component mounts the function, it runs without clicking the button. The other one is a callback function. It will run when the user clicks the button.